# How to modify a changing sequential output to a random one

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="changeText" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tvShows = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    setInterval(change, 2000);
    function change() {
     elem.innerHTML = tvShows[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= tvShows.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs the list in the array in the sequence that it is written in the array. My question is how to change the output to random. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will help you generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your js function to pick a random element from array. Like below

```
  var tvShows = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men',
      'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'
  ];

  var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
  setInterval(change, 1000);

  function change() {
      var counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * tvShows.length);
      elem.innerHTML = tvShows[counter];
  }
```